# Why committing transaction in each iteration of a WHILE loop does not prevent transaction log to grow up?

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, transaction-log

I am trying to delete millions of records from a database table.

I used a WHILE loop in order delete TOP 25000 rows in every iteration with committing them.

My assumption was, if I delete portion of rows and commit in every iteration I would prevent the transaction log to grow up.

I did *something like below*:

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN

-- Logic to BREAK the loop like if no rows left to delete
IF ...
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DELETE TOP 25000
   FROM FooBar
   Where SomeDate<AnotherDate
  COMMIT

END
```

However I am ending '***The transaction log for database 'FooBar' is full.***'

What should I do to prevent the transaction log to grow up? -Committing does not delete it?

Comment: What is the recovery mode on the database?  It needs to be simple.  And you don't need a transaction here.  A single statement is a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Commiting Transaction writes logs, because when you restore database by log , it will be recovered from committed transactions.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? Finding the same issue...if you got solution, can you pls help me with that?